# How to get a full name from user input in SWI-Prolog and display it as an output?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to SWI-Prolog and still learning it. I'm making a simple program to ask for user's full name and display the output. However, I've been struggling on how to get a full name from the user input together with spaces between firstname, midname, and last name from a single input. When I try to display an output that is only the first name, the output is just a code.

Here's what I wrote so far :

```
name:-nl,
write('Write your full name: '),read(FName),
write(FName).
```

Here's the input and the output.
[Prolog_Name_Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN4kL.png)

This is the output that I want.

```
?- name.
Write your full name: First Middle Last.
First Middle Last
true.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal `read(X)` reads the next **term** from the current input stream and unify it with `X`. In order for the predicate to correctly read a full name, you need to type that name **enclosed in single quotes** and finish the input with a **period**. For example:

```
?- name.

Write your full name: 'First Middle Last'.
First Middle Last
true.
```

You can also use the predicate [`read_line_to_string/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_line_to_string/2), in which case the quotes and period should not be typed:

```
name :-
    nl,
    write('Write your full name: '),
    read_line_to_string(user_input, FName),
    write(FName).
```

Example:

```
?- name.

Write your full name: First Niddle Last
First Niddle Last
true.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I figured it out but it's good to see that there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered the solution and it's really simple. Full name is a combination of characters therefore I need to put single quotation mark at the beginning and at the end of the name in the input. I don't know if it is my ignorance or I feel like this kind of thing is rarely explained in other guides.

The input should look like this.

```
?- name.
Write your full name: 'First Middle Last'.
First Middle Last
true.
```